# "JGitInternalException: username is not given" generated from NGit when trying to clone via SSH form Git repository hosted on TFS on-premise

Tags: c#, git, mono, jgit, ngit

I am using NGit api to connect to git repositories and manipulate them.

I have a case where I want to connect to my git repository hosted on TFS on premise. I create ssh key, insert it inside repository everything goes well. But when I want to clone repository I get a message from *JGitInternalException* saying

> ssh://servername:22/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/gitrepo: username is
>   not given

I assume I must use url that contains username inside url like it is defines in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts

for example ssh://username@servername:22/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/gitrepo or so, but when I click on "Clone repo" in browser I just get the 1st URL.

Or should I change something inside JschConfigSessionFactory. Any help or workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: the URL drops the user info so its not visible

Comment: Oh, I see, I've manually added ssh://username@servername:22/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/gitrepo and it seems that clone is working. Thanks